# Disabling System Interrupts in Windows 7 - (high CPU usage, semi solved)

Tags: windows, cpu, acpi, interrupts

I know the system interrupts topic is pretty common with varying solutions but I had a question about how to implement a solution in Windows 7 the way I did in Ubuntu 12.04.

Background:

- Bought an **ASUS K53SV model laptop** in May 2011 and it worked great
  until a couple of months ago when the CPU started to act up.
- After using a Latency checker, found the culprit was ACPI.sys
- Tried a number of solutions until the computer became unusable
- Installed Ubuntu 12.04 over everything
- Problem persisted with kworker taking up CPU
- Fixed the issue by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high)
- GPE04 was acting up so I disabled it and things were back to normal

TLDR:

I need to have Windows 7 running for work though and I was wondering if there was a way to find the specific interrupt and disable it [the same way I did in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high).

I have a suspicion that the interrupts are caused by the dedicated NVidia 540M GPU since I had trouble getting it to work in Ubuntu and video crashes became more common around the time the issues first started. I've tried almost everything on the web and the issue persists and I imagine it's something hardware related.

EDIT:

I've already tried reinstalling Windows, fan speed and updating the BIOS. I'm asking more about disabling interrupts in Windows 7, I've accepted that the main problem is not solveable.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it may render it moot: Have you re-installed windows and verified that the problem still exists?  Have you tried updated drivers for your video card?

Comment: I've reinstalled windows multiple times and the problem persists. Also tried latest and multiple video card drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same issue, although my notebook (Asus K53SC) was about 20 months old when the problem arose. Symptoms were the same: ACPI interrupts eating one CPU at 100%, the fan is constantly running at what sounds like maximum speed. I've installed Ubuntu and the problem was there too (GPE06 in my case).

The root cause of the problem was... dust! I've disassembled and cleaned my notebook and interrupts are gone both in Windows and Ubuntu.

Look at what I found after disassembly:
[image]

Compare to cleaned:
[image]

[Disassembly guide](http://allurgroceries.com/asus_disassembly/K53%20Series%20Guide%20Chapter%2002-v1.0.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a ton, this actually worked! The guide was especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [other users with an ASUS laptop](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/153875-hardware-interrupts-load-cpu/page__st__20__p__979461#entry979461) and the ACPI.sys DPC issue is caused by [CPU throttling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_throttling) to avoid overheating.

Use [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to increase the CPU cooler fan speed. Also call the ASUS support for an updated BIOS which includes a better fan management.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.

I've tried modifying the speed of the fan but it seems impossible on this laptop. It shouldn't matter though because the fan is constantly running at what sounds like maximum speed.

I've tried updating the BIOS, no changes. ASUS won't support me because I've installed my own version of Windows 7 as the recovery disks did not work.

Comment: try this tool: http://sdrv.ms/P6RKKe

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with high system interrupts for several months as well on windows 7. Sometimes it could run for 3 days before it would start causing slow downs, and at other times it could be less than 24 hours before it began.

I tried every suggestion that I could find on the web and nothing helped. Finally I happened to come across this link  http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01817290

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Click System and Security
3. Click System
4. In the left hand column click Advanced System Settings
5. Under Performance click Settings
6. Click Adjust for best performance
7. Click Apply.

My PC now runs much faster and no system interrupts. Can run for weeks at a time with no slow downs. Hope this helps others who cannot find a workable solution for system interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with acpi.sys; in my case it was due to a HDD caddy that I used to replace the DVD drive with an SSD.  Some of these caddys come with a switch to configure the device in a diagnostics mode that causes this constant high CPU usage, so the solution is to change the physical switch setting and then the CPU consumption drops to 0.

Here are some more details and pictures of the switch: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/second-hdd-caddy-with-a-flip-switch.739486/